# Project Error - Adding a Space in src/components/canvas/Computers.jsx Fixes It - Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm working on a project, and I've come across a peculiar issue. To make my project work correctly, I had to add a space within the code of Computers.jsx, which is located in src/components/canvas/. Without this space, my project encounters an error.

I'm curious to understand why adding this space resolves the issue. Could someone provide insights into why this might be happening, or suggest a more proper solution? I want to ensure that my project is stable and that I'm not using a workaround that might cause issues down the line.

this is my code:

```
import {Suspense, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls,Preload,meshBounds,useGLTF  } from '@react-three/drei';
import CanvasLoader from '../Loader';


const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF('./desktop_pc/scene.gltf');
  
  return (
    <mesh>
       <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor='black' />

       <pointLight intensity={1} />
       <primitive
        object={computer.scene } 
        scale={0.75} />
    </mesh>
  ) 
}
 
const ComputersCanvas = () =>{
  return(
    <Canvas
    frameloop='demand'
    shadows
    camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
    gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}  
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers/>
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all/> 
    </Canvas>
  );
 
} 
export default ComputersCanvas
```

I initially noticed the issue when my project wasn't functioning as expected. I examined the code in Computers.jsx, and I saw that adding a single space at a specific location within the file resolved the problem. However, I'm not sure why adding a space would have this effect.

I tried the following:

Reviewed the relevant code in Computers.jsx to identify the exact location where adding a space made a difference.
Experimented with other potential changes or adjustments in the code, but the issue persisted.
Checked for any potential syntax or runtime errors in the console, but there were no error messages related to this issue.
I was expecting that the project should work without needing this unusual modification. I want to understand the underlying cause and find a more appropriate solution if possible.

Here is a live example of the issue [text](https://youtu.be/zTP6T7famMs)

Here is the full repo [text](https://github.com/JorgeBuk0IV/Portfolio-.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial inspection -**
Actually adding a space isn't resolving the issue, that's just an illusion. Basically when you make any change (Even adding or removing space), your app is getting hot reloaded and it renders the expected output. But now at this point if you reload the page it will still fail.

**Root cause -**
On initial load, `useGLTF` in `<Computers/>` component starts loading the image. So `Suspense` in `ComputersCanvas` component renders `CanvasLoader` component. Now `CanvasLoader` returns a `<div>`, but as clearly logged by three.js in browser console, It doesn't accepts `<div>`(Please see attached console log snapshot). Now by the time you change something in code (including add/remove spaces) your app get's hot reloaded and as at this point image is already loaded, Suspense doesn't show `CanvasLoader` and hence it starts working as expected.

[image]

**Solution -** Removing `<div>` from CanvasLoader fixes the issue -

```
import React from 'react'

const Loader = () => {
  return (
    "Loader"
  )
}

export default Loader
```

Comment: thanks bro it did make it you are a G